# Printing interface-ipaddress through single command (piped)

Tags: ifconfig

**ifconfig** gives following output:

```
   eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:87:0e:z3:e7:11  
              UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:35767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35767 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5053027 (5.0 MB)  TX bytes:5053027 (5.0 MB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:80:66:m0:00:01  
          inet addr:192.168.139.1  Bcast:192.168.139.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I presently need output like

```
eth0   
wlan0   127.0.0.1
vmnet1  192.168.139.1
```

so i run command

```
ifconfig | awk '/encap|inet addr/{  print }'
```

but i am stuck now, as i need to combine 2 lines based on weather the next line contains the ipaddress pattern. Though shell script may do the trick ,
But i need a simple single command solution.
Though for loops are there in awk , but forward looking into next line , matching  & then printing on console is challenge for me .

or is there  a simple command / flag for achieving such purpose ?

route command seems to do the trick (awk field extraction!!) , but it doesnot list the inactive interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally found ifconfig based solution!

```
String s="ifconfig | awk -F '[ :]' '/encap|inet addr/{ if($1 != \"\" ){ print $1 \":\" $13 } else print $13 }'| awk -F \":\" '{print $1}'| awk '{  curr=$1 ; if(!system(\"echo \"$1\"|grep ^[0-9]>/dev/null\")) {print prev \"\\t : \" curr;prev=\"\"} else { if(prev!=\"\") {print prev \"\\t : not assigned\" }; prev=$1 }   }'"
```

explanation :

```
root$ ifconfig | awk -F '[ :]' '/encap|inet addr/{ if($1 != "" ){ print $1 ":" $13 } else print $13 }'| awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
eth0
lo
127.0.0.1
vmnet1
192.168.139.1
vmnet8
192.168.152.1
wlan0
10.208.7.86
```

so , i have piped the above output to another awk command:

```
| awk '{  curr=$1 ; if(!system("echo "$1"|grep ^[0-9]>/dev/null")) {print prev "\t : " curr;prev=""} else { if(prev!="") {print prev "\t : not assigned" }; prev=$1 }   }'
```

here , if i find two consecutive interface names, then i print the name of **prev**ious interface with custom messge "**not assigned**"  .if i get numeric  pattern in string then current string(ipaddress) along with the **prev**ious interface name is printed !

Answer (score 3):

If you're running GNU/Linux:

```
for DEV in /sys/class/net/*; do
    printf "%-10s %s\n" ${DEV##*/} $(ip addr show ${DEV##*/} | \
      sed -rne '/inet/s:\s+inet\s+([0-9.]+).*:\1:gp');
done
```

or if `ifconfig` is a requirement:

```
for DEV in /sys/class/net/*; do
    printf "%-10s %s\n" ${DEV##*/} $(ifconfig ${DEV##*/} | \
      sed -rne '/inet adr/s/\s+inet adr:([0-9.]+).*/\1/gp');
done
```

it yields

```
eth0       192.168.10.34
eth1       
lo         127.0.0.1
...
```

Requires `iproute2` though.

Comment: Also requires Linux! The OP doesn't say what OS this has to work for... although the `ifconfig` output in the question does look a whole lot like Linux ;)

Comment: Well, Good spot! I don't know about *BSD but IIRC Mac OSX also includes /sys. Too bad I no longer have a Mac under my hand :D .

Comment: first one was okay , but the second one doesn't work properly on debian (simply lists out i'faces without ipaddresses);
Though i am expecting a simple command (as i have to execute it using jsch library, so the escape sequences in first solution might prove problemmatic in my case!)

Comment: It is possible with a single `sed` one-liner but I'm not familiar enough with buffer handling with `sed`. This said, I doubt a script without escape chars is possible. Strange that the second sample doesn't work though because I tested it on Linux Mint and it worked as expected.

Comment: The first doesn't work for interface aliases (like eth0:1), because `ip addr show eth0` will show all show also eth0:1, which the script does not expect

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig -a | awk '/Link/ {n=$1} /addr/ {print n, substr($2,index($2,":")+1))}'

Simply, grab the name, then when address comes along, print the name and the address, which follows the colon.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with just `ifconfig` and `awk`. Should work also for aliased interfaces (eth0:1) and vlan interfaces (eth0.1):

```
ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"; } { if ($7 != "addr:") {print $1,$7} }'
```

`RS` parameter in awk is record separator and we set it to 2 newlines. It causes awk to merge all info about each interface into single line. I also suppress printing interfaces which don't have any IPv4 address configured.

I use this command to show for each interface its IP and also its resolved hostname:

```
ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n\n"; } { if ($7 != "addr:") {print $1,$7} }' | sed 's/addr://g' | while read iface ip; do
  echo $iface $ip $(getent hosts | awk '/^'$ip'/ {print $2}');
done
```

The output looks like:

```
bond0 10.126.226.102 deh137.abc.biz.
bond0:1 10.126.227.10 aeudi64.abc.biz.
bond0:7 10.126.226.141 rtlci22.abc.biz.
bond1.625 10.126.216.142
bond1.654 10.126.228.102 deh137s.abc.biz.
```

**EDIT:** Updated the last command to work both with DNS and with /etc/hosts based resolving.